# method startStories in class StoriesProgressView cannot be applied to given types

Tags: integer

I'm creating a social media app that has a Story feature like facebook then I encounter this problem

```
'startStories()' in 'jp.shts.android.storiesprogressview.StoriesProgressView' cannot be applied to '(int)'
error: method startStories in class StoriesProgressView cannot be applied to given types;
storiesProgressView.startStories(counter);
^
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here's my code

```
private void getStories(String userid){
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        storyids = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Story")
                .child(userid);
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                images.clear();
                storyids.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelStory modelStory = snapshot1.getValue(ModelStory.class);
                    long timecurrent = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        images.add(modelStory.imageUri);

                        storyids.add(modelStory.storyid);

                }
                storiesProgressView.setStoriesCount(images.size());
                storiesProgressView.setStoryDuration(5000L);
                storiesProgressView.setStoriesListener(StoryChatViewActivity.this);
                storiesProgressView.startStories(counter);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(images.get(counter)).into(imageView);
                addView(storyids.get(counter));
                seenNumber(storyids.get(counter));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

PLease help me finding the solution here.

Comment: Is this any particular language, and if so, which?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: This is my first time coding, not actually coding but I just editing it because it is a code template. So I definitely not know what that error means. Hehe

Comment: It happens inside StoryChatViewActivity.java

Comment: The error is in this line storiesProgressView.startStories(counter); the word counter has red underline

Comment: `reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: How to solve that?

Comment: Start by figuring out what it means, and what `startStories` is supposed to do.